# React: import different files depending on env

Tags: reactjs, import, react-redux, create-react-app

I need to import different .js files inside another .js file(based on **production** or **development** mode), how can I do that?

Here is the example:

*MyCar.js*

If "development"

```
import * as cars from 'test_cars';
```

If "production"

```
import * as cars from 'real_cars';
```

And then i need to use **cars**, for example like here:

```
cars.paint('red');
```

Is it possible to do without require (this method send me error)?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50688934/conditional-import-based-on-environment-variable

Comment: The logic sounds backwards btw....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditional Import based on environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50688934/conditional-import-based-on-environment-variable)

Comment: Write me the code, how can i use then "cars" variable? In that example "css" import, it means it cant be undefined inside .js file. How to return import result from "export"?