# how to use a config file with react

Tags: reactjs

in React, I'd like to do something similar to Angular's environments file. 
this is to adjust my api endpoints and other values depending on my environment:
(note, using typescript)

```
**package.json:**
**angular**:  
"start": "ng serve --configuration=dif",

**react:**
"start": "SET REACT_APP_CONFIG=dif & react-scripts start",
"pl2": "SET REACT_APP_CONFIG=pl2 & react-scripts start",
```

based on the REACT_APP_CONFIG value I want to do an import statement:

```
 //this doesn't work of course....
 import config from './config/config' + process.env.REACT_APP_CONFIG;
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

*Well this answer is absolutely wrong since OP is not on a Mac. I'll leave it in case anyone stumbles upon it that's on a Mac.*

In your package.json, you can write your command like so:

```
"start": "REACT_APP_CONFIG=dif node start react-scripts",
"p12": "REACT_APP_CONFIG=p12 node start react-scripts",
```

Essentially, if you want to set an env variable and make it available to a running node script, you simply do that just before running it. It's basically what you were trying to do but you want to do it w/o the & and you don't need the SET.

I'm not sure the `node start react-scripts` is correct. You'll have to adjust that to your set up.

Comment: SET is required for Windows and the next commands are separated by Ampersand symbol.

Comment: Aaah, my bad. I did not know that. I'm also surprised that it's single ampersand and not double for next command. Thanks for the knowledge!

Comment: The solution to dynamic import, seems to be a duplicate post 1. wrap the logic inside a component's componentWillMount event. 2. Using promise you can handle css specific things please refer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50688934/conditional-import-based-on-environment-variable

Comment: It should be double ampersand, might be he made a typo .

Comment: Ah, ok I see @Senthil

Comment: the issue isn't setting the variable... it's using that variable in an IMPORT statement to pull the correct config object. :)

Answer (score 0):

This might be a duplicate question ref here : [Conditional Import based on environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50688934/conditional-import-based-on-environment-variable)

The solution to dynamic import, seems to be a duplicate post 1. wrap the logic inside a component's componentWillMount event. 2. Using promise you can handle css specific things