# Unable to do Conditional import of file in React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, typescript, ecmascript-2018

I am having issues importing a JSON file depending on a `process.env.WORLD` value in my React Typescript app. This is done in a `.tsx` file defining a React Context, and no React components are used here.

The JSON file can be loaded without problems when we ignore the `process.env` variable.

```js
import data from '../main.json';
```

- TS file loading the JSON file: `src/contexts/world.tsx`
- JSON file: `src/main.json`

---

In my first attempt, I tried

```
let file;
if (process.env.WORLD == 'main') {
    file = '../main.json';
} else {
    file = '../test.json';
}

import data from file;
```

but got the error

```
Import in body of module; reorder to top  import/first
```

---

Tried using dynamic `import`

```
const data = await import(
    process.env.WORLD == 'main'
      ? '../main.json'
      : '../test.json'
  );
```

but my setup does not allow a top-level `await`

```
Module parse failed: Cannot use keyword 'await' outside an async function
```

---

Tried using `require` instead of `import`

```
let file;
if (process.env.WORLD === 'main') {
  file = '../main.json';
} else {
  file = '../test.json';
}

const data = require(file);
```

but it almost works except that the file cannot be found

```
contexts sync:2 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '../main.json'
```

Strangely, there is no problem using the same file path with `import` as shown in the first example in this question.

---

Typescript target is `ES2018`, and React 18 is used.

Why is the file not found when using `require`, and how can we solve this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditional Import based on environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50688934/conditional-import-based-on-environment-variable)

Comment: @evolutionxbox Nope, that question is trying to solve the `import/no-dynamic-require` linting error. The non-working solution there requires the use of a React class component, but I need to load the JSON file without using a component (uses a Context)

Comment: If you are using `create-react-app`, then have you read the section on [environment variables](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/), specifically, the naming requirements? Regardless of naming issues, why do you need it at the top level of your module? (Why can't you get the data in an async function?) You haven't shown in your question why this is a problem for you.

Comment: @jsejcksn If we dont do it at the top level of the module, then the other place is inside the Context Provider. Doing an async function call in there probably requires an `isLoading` variable to be provided by the context, which makes it a little more troublesome when used in the React component that uses the context

Comment: Thanks for the docs to React environmental variables, I have made the changes based on it.

Answer (score 1):

In [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72925519/unable-to-do-conditional-import-of-file-in-react-app?noredirect=1#comment128816854_72925519), you added information which implies that the external JSON data is being used as part of the `value` of a `ContextProvider`.

By fetching (or importing) the JSON data dynamically just before render, you can pass it via props to your context provider on the initial render, then memoize it in a `ref`. Below is a working example in a Stack Overflow snippet which uses object URLs in place of your local file specifiers.

Note that there are many considerations involved in how to optimize external data loading, and your question does not provide much detail regarding your scenario, but the approach that works best for your app will depend on those details. **In any case, what you've described in the question would be better handled by re-writing the contents of a single JSON file on disk (based on the environment variable) before building or running your app each time.** This would need to be handled **outside** the React app by an external process (like an npm script, for example), and would allow you to avoid the scenario entirely, while also optimizing the build result with static imports.

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=5&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMAiB5AsnAMyghDgHIpUMBaAExIHo0AbYJAOxjIG4AoUSLDgBvXnDi0kBFAFdm8FAGdEVGABoxcNJRQwkAYQickAD3WaAyjCjAMuCJI3iZig0b1mncF0mQEvMACeYEgq6DAAcg5IAcGhyOEAosxIIBzmAL6ExKQUqjy8vEEhcABSikaYuihwALwimsB6IIoAXHCK1sDsAOYA2gC6fOKsnQAqTSntnTa9fBl8vAwMcACC7HDdTcAozHAAbrsyocDK7BDwlACOMsCUtHBKcMxGPY-KMAAWp0srp3DneA+B4QGQwRTASRwL6hNDuUzwMDEfaQpBQVq8OHsTpwABWFXYhmMZjqWh0eiJHhgAAoZOxJARukgHk86QBrc4Adw2T3KlWqAEpFgQ6RhgEYygSAArI1FQODU4Rob7MWiUdhqCTVDLtUTiZXAVXq9oJDBRSTDLUwFDtPnsKrW+YCk2qZKpdINfVGHGUAiknx+am0QWWygwGRQDbUzTiAA8+KMlIRADoZRAUZJ5YdmMdasJfcm0BH1TAMgA+GPiJUqtUcDKV2MMBOE+FmVOyzMV8RC3j13gi9hiiWrMBgBXOsIYN1pTierTe+DCJqpRSa0YwCYwFJZeo+JNmanN-cwHuaMMRqMN2jAfZd8T32OfACMZeE68328bz7v97gsbkP6-iIy4tMmIAoGA1LUiBmrdJIJgCnUZYKrGrBwGySCBHmcGmOWS7NBkjasGWAoCvWQF-gwAENgw163poPZ9sUoR2jKoDbPsoT1AARhAEApCgGwAD4AnIewiewMggNxaJwCJMzdD0fDMZKRgWGiOysAAXig3EpKSrE2CAHGhCJdrqTYuzADpelIIMckiHAfQYYE0xdL0Ay2gSFmadZun6QshQDkOGzaKgeh2tg3G4kgGAAKpQHs1KuJZ2n+UgXlqRpVk2SkE4Kb0c5YjizYGRY2ARMmBU9MABCBMl2VpbZPZeti8B6RA3GkuwSCcnAABCLzcdSfTNgMmrCMx7RkBBYCsGgujiuwTYEmQGQtXA56RnAcUIAAMoW5JIFFMXxft1IddxjGFEogSDoQoowEtmzsNs1rMMg9KydSiF6nAyxwGMnyhFY6BsnA2CcVABAvH1cJQoor2jkg8CKIJtC8SYEgQEgiNkPAnwoJxcDmkgZDKAABkiEBoLjigU14AMVHAnJk8wewQiAci6CcBNohlmjFYixC04oyj1H94gcPsuqVuIAMWKA3N6NChPwE085yA8MlwEgTTA-KABE4HdIbcDQHAht6J0hty4giSrPoYwAPqrFKUrO6U5URM7ABiACSe2JO0uC6J8yZQOjJA-X+cAAAzJgArHAAD85Am+wZBwNN1tcF44hZE8UooLAmmxsgcJQLQsbVZq1VlmWXiBZoAP+xsgSgvKs2al8-ycqCqodAIzCBHAOuG8myYMBnybNmbFsT1PuezwShuMys3FgqrIPWmg4OQ2iMMQHD0QdEjISo+jmPY7jmcE0ToToKLHwQC3KwdxGzw07shCGrjdcQBZmzDmStmA823h0EIaBapsHlJyfWjwNidVOvAXae034Kk5N8ZUWhBKPGYMzHWBAUbKmZAwAQ0A9C0GdILBckDYowNkvUamz9kzS2TAgB2TtXbu09t7P2gdEh1FqPUMgGcyCVjTmFHmkVoqxRgAlZgio7YgTaE5GaZBNRkG4po8gaAyDjTtu+SYGV04oG6Joys61KztGkRFAkJ15GKOURRVR7Q+hkCMGTLRMB+66Pxp8SgZNDEUWMVuUx+NcZ5ysaeeWKw4quEICQz40JAE9BRhA4M1pMFk0oC9RB7w7poAeoOJ6RgAGq10OTCGABpAAhAKWhbUrQ1HqCgTk5j4DUnaZ0pJMBlTJSgYwqApEV5GB+osOJEN5TQQ2DCB64ZKCIVoHdFAxlikUKEPAr4BSlApTKewDEUyhYiAZLIeQ7QskoB3I8DpGtNk0kUEMxkaIJp7LRDAXUU1yDNjWutSZ85mk6AwAgPi8B6imiwHgQ64VfBgqDDTKS6RkzpJgNOdI-VAj+1oNSCgYKyACgaaGVQoKLgRw4JmaMv5YxWBsHYaIgE4yGXTHKEQk9kzCCuRkcsds4wjjHAwRllFmUZjRIBRstLbAwHsJIO811+CvSeu9T6lKexAA)

```html
<div id="root"></div><script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.18.8/babel.min.js"></script><script>Babel.registerPreset('tsx', {presets: [[Babel.availablePresets['typescript'], {allExtensions: true, isTSX: true}]]});</script>
<script type="text/babel" data-type="module" data-presets="tsx,react">

// import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
// import {
//   default as React,
//   createContext,
//   StrictMode,
//   useContext,
//   useRef,
//   type ReactNode,
//   type ReactElement,
// } from 'react';

// This Stack Overflow snippet demo uses UMD modules
// instead of the commented import statments above
const {
  createContext,
  StrictMode,
  useContext,
  useRef,
} = React;

type JsonData = {
  items: string[];
  listTitle: string;
};

// An initial value is not required as long as this
// is not used outside the context provider:
const jsonContext = createContext(undefined as unknown as JsonData);

function JsonProvider ({children, data}: {
  children: ReactNode;
  data: JsonData;
}): ReactElement {
  const ref = useRef(data);
  return (
    <jsonContext.Provider value={ref.current}>
     {children}
    </jsonContext.Provider>
  );
}

function App (): ReactElement {
  const {items, listTitle} = useContext(jsonContext);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{listTitle}</h1>
      <ul>
        {items.map((item, index) => (<li key={index}>{item}</li>))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

type JsonPrimitive = boolean | null | number | string;
type JsonSerializable = JsonPrimitive | JsonSerializable[] | { [key: string]: JsonSerializable };

function createJsonObjectUrl (serializable: JsonSerializable): string {
  const json = JSON.stringify(serializable);
  const blob = new Blob([json], {type: 'application/json'});
  return URL.createObjectURL(blob);
}

async function inititalRender () {
  // The Stack Overflow code snippet sandbox doesn't have Node's `process`,
  // so we'll simulate it here:
  const process = {
    env: {
      // Simulate that it could be either "main" or "test"
      REACT_APP_JSON_FILE: Math.random() < 0.5 ? 'main' : 'test',
    } as Partial<Record<string, string>>,
  };

  // In your app, this would simply be "../main.json" or "../test.json",
  // but the Stack Overflow code snippet sandbox doesn't have access to
  // your local files, so we'll simulate the specifier with an object URL
  // (which can also be fetched/imported):
  const specifier = process.env.REACT_APP_JSON_FILE === 'main'
    ? createJsonObjectUrl({
      items: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
      listTitle: 'main',
    })
    : createJsonObjectUrl({
      items: ['one', 'two', 'three'],
      listTitle: 'test',
    });

  // Use fetch to get the data (we're in an async function, so that's OK!)
  const data = await (await fetch(specifier)).json();

  // Or (in the future) dynamic import with an assertion:
  // const {default: data} = await import(specifier, {assert: {type: 'json'}});

  const reactRoot = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!);
  reactRoot.render(
    <StrictMode>
      <JsonProvider {...{data}}>
        <App />
      </JsonProvider>
    </StrictMode>
  );
}

inititalRender();

</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Could importing both files then choose the right file be a fit for you ?

```
import main from '../main.json';
import test from  '../test.json';


let file;
if (process.env.WORLD == 'main') {
   file = main;
} else {
   file = test
}
```

or use `react.lazy` :

```
const Questions = React.lazy(() => { 
    if (process.env.WORLD == 'main') {
       import('../main.json'))
    } else {
       import('../test.json'))
    }
 }
```

Comment: Importing both files works for me! Both JSON files are tiny so this is fine

Comment: How should the `Questions` component in the `react.lazy` approach be used?